# How to hide flat rate when free shipping is applied in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a situation here, I have been through to all related questions but couldn't find sufficient solution for this.
Ok, I have free shipping method active from system configuration > shipping methods and set to anything £50 or greater than free shipping is active which works fine. now problem is i still see flatrate/standard shipping under free shipping which is by logic wrong.. kindly advise how to auto disable when free shipping in place? Magento 1.9.2.1

Would appreciate your patience and response as i know there are plenty of similar questions there in stackoverflow but none of them work out for me.

Regards

Adam

Comment: Please provide extensive code samples so we can understand the situation better.

Answer (score 5):

Just to Note: there is more than one way to do this through code, this one is the easiest to accomplish the scenario above.

Let me first comment on `i still see flatrate/standard shipping under free shipping which is by logic wrong`, the idea of showing both "Free Shipping" and "Flat Rate" is the case of your store showing multiple options with difference in the speed of shipping, so you could have a flat rate for (1 day shipping) and a free shipping (5-7 Days).

Now to accomplish the case where you want only to show one shipping option if the subtotal is over a certain amount, this is where you make use of 
`Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules`, please note that for this method you will need to disable `Free Shipping`, where you can set it as below:

[image]

Then add the rule you need under conditions :

[image]

After that Magento needs to know the action to apply for this condition you setup. In this case we want it to apply free shipping if the subtotal is over $50 in this example.

[image]

Now you should be able to see "Flat Rate shipping" showing $0.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Rabee

Thank you so much for your response. It kind of worked for me but now got another issue. I am using Multi-Flat shipping extension. 
In order to use following delivery options;

- Free Delivery over £50
- Standard Delivery £4.95
- Next Day Delivery £6.95
- Saturday Delivery £9.95

Now i can achieve first 2 (Free and Standard) using your method works fine. Thank you. But remaining 2 (Next day and Saturday) are now showing to £0.00. 
I have enclosed a snapshot here. Please advise. Thanks and regards

Adam

Comment: I never used the extension to be honest, I will try to look at it once I get the chance.